# network programming library for java similar to scapy which is for python

Tags: java, python, networking, network-programming, scapy

I am looking for a Java library similar to what Scapy is for python, anyone aware of any library?

I did search in the internet but could not find any library which is similar to scapy for java.

Comment: Just googling 'packet manipulation for java' gave me this lib: https://www.pcap4j.org/. Does this not fit your needs?

Comment: Yes, it does fit my need.